# Ways to improve UIWebView scrolling performance?

Tags: ios, performance, uiwebview, webkit, scroll

I am building an application that includes a `UIWebView` containing a large number of images, CSS, embedded video, and JavaScript tap handlers. Scrolling performance is stuttery and I am looking for insight into the most effective ways to improve this.

Which if any of the following characteristics lead to laggy `UIWebView` scrolling? What other factors may be hindering performance?

- Quantity of images

  - Should I be removing images from the DOM as the user scrolls past them, and adding them back if they scroll back up?
- Size of images

  - Will Retina-quality images in a web view affect scrolling performance a lot more than smaller versions would?
- Image scaling

  - Would resizing the images ahead of time make a big difference, rather than relying on the web view to scale based on declarations like `width: 100%;`?
- CSS

  - I have avoided `box-shadow`, but are there other CSS properties that are also known for adversely affecting scrolling performance?

If there are any other resources or tools that can be used for profiling, I've love to hear about them.

Answer (score 8):

This is the answer I got from Apple Developer Technical Support a while ago:

> At this time, we do not provide any mechanisms to optimize the rendering of UIWebView.
>   The reason you see a difference is due to Mobile Safari and UIWebView not using the same rendering engine.
>
> The performance is dependent on the content loaded. If there are javascripts running or plugins being used, this can hinder the performance.
>
> I recommend that you file a bug report at http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/ detailing your situation. This will also keep you informed on the status of your bug report.

A possible alternative to UIWebView would be the open-source DTCoreText library: https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText, which powers the Float Reader app: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/float-reader/id447992005?mt=8

Comment: I know that the performance is dependent on the content loaded. I am looking to understand _which_ changes to my content (e.g. smaller images, fewer images, avoiding certain CSS properties, etc.) will have the biggest effect.

Answer (score 5):

The guys at LinkedIn have done extensive work with UIWebView and HTML5 on their iPad application. Their entire feed which is heavy with images, texts and videos is rendered inside a UIWebView.

The following blog post should give you lots of starting points to performance improvements

[LinkedIn for iPad: 5 techniques for smooth infinite scrolling in HTML5](http://engineering.linkedin.com/linkedin-ipad-5-techniques-smooth-infinite-scrolling-html5)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue a while ago.  I found that putting the webview inside of a scrollview improved scroll performance dramatically.  After the webview finished loading I disabled scrolling on the webview, set the webview's frame and the scrollview's contentSize to be the size of the webview's content.

```
-(void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {   
    float size = [[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.offsetHeight"] floatValue];
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, size)];
    [webView setFrame:CGRectMake(webView.frame.origin.x,
                                 webView.frame.origin.y,
                                 webView.frame.size.width,
                                 size)];

    [(UIScrollView*)[webView.subviews objectAtIndex:0] setScrollEnabled:NO];
}
```

I'm assuming that the webview doesn't load an image until it is about to appear on screen, which caused the stuttering, and by putting it in a scrollview and setting the frame to the content size it must load them ahead of time, but I'm not certain.  I'm also sure this has consequences (ie, increased memory usage up front), but I never had any problems doing it this way.

Comment: I cannot down-vote yet, but this is a serious no-no. This solution causes the entire webView to be drawn into it's CALayer (invalidating UIWebView's tiling rendering mechanism), causing a huge memory use. OP's description of his pages, "containing a large number of images, CSS, embedded video, and JavaScript tap handlers" would cause the app the use excessive amount of memory.

Comment: So what you're saying is I traded memory for performance?  That's kind of what I figured.  I agree that it's not a great solution, but it was the only way I could find to improve scrolling.  And given I knew exactly what was going to be loaded into the webview ahead of time and all assets were bundled with the app, I had no problem doing it this way.

Comment: Well, this kind of trading is very dangerous with UIWebView, because it grows in memory very fast and aggressively. And when content become larger and more complex, you will soon find a barrage of didReceiveMemoryWarning-s and eventually crashes.

Comment: I don't disagree with what you say.  The title of the question is ways to improve UIWebView scrolling.  This is one way that comes at a cost, as everything does.  In my case, and possibly the OP's, I am able to afford that cost and it provided a much more usable webview.

Comment: I have used the exact method that rjowens posted. What I added is a way of "dequeueing" the content after it gets shifted offscreen past what would be deemed "usable" by your project. In a way would be considered soft pagination. It gains on both memory and scrolling performance. Specially if your content is provided linearly. So I would up vote both rjowens comment for being bang on and Leo's comment for bringing up a big concern

Comment: Can you share anything else about your web view "dequeueing" mechanism?

Comment: Specifically, I'm interested in knowing how you remove HTML without changing the height of the scrollable content area.